# Using jQuery $.proxy with $.filter passing "this" as reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I have access to both `this`, one referring to the parent object and the other referring to the $('.report') DOM object being screened in the jQuery filter function?

In the following case, the DOM object `this` is overwritten by the `$.proxy` and `this` now refers to the var `parentObj`. What is the best way to handle a situation like this?

```
var parentObj =

   {

    getId: , //some function that returns the id by value 

    render: function(){

        $('.report').filter($.proxy(function(index) {

           return $(this).data('id') == this.getId($(this).data('value'))

        }, this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used `$.proxy()` to pass a custom execution context to the callback, `this` inside the callback does not refer to the current element - it refers to the `parentObj` object.

So to refer to the current `report` element use the second argument to the callback function which is the current element being filtered

```
var parentObj = {

    getId: , //some function that returns the id by value 

    render: function () {
        $('.report').filter($.proxy(function (index, el) {
            //use el here to refer tot the current element
            return $(el).data('id') == this.getId($(el).data('value'))
        }, this));
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gzf33/)

Comment: Yes, this works for this particular scenario. My question was really intended for any situations similar to this where the `this` reference in a `$.proxy()` function gets overwritten and a backup parameter like `el` in the above case is not provided. How would I generally handle that?

Comment: in that case you can use a closure variable to refer to the actual object instead of using $.proxy() like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gzf33/2/